# How to run onLocationChanged method when app is closed (with onStop method)

Tags: java, android, locationlistener

I have this method, which manages my location:

```
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        if(inRun){
            Clocation myLocation = new Clocation(location, this.useMetricUnits());
            this.updateSpeed(myLocation);
            this.updateDistance(myLocation);
            this.updateAverageSpeed(this.distance, this.chronometer);
            if (activity.getText().toString() != ActivityRecongnizedService.getActivity()) {
                activity.setText(ActivityRecongnizedService.getActivity());
                activityTimer.start();
            }


            switch (activity.getText().toString()) {
                case "STILL": still = true; break;
                case "IN VEHICLE": inVehicle = true; break;
                case "ON BICYCLE": onBicycle = true; break;
                case "ON FOOT": onFoot = true; break;
                case "RUNNING": running = true; break;
                case "WALKING": walking = true;break;
                case "TILTING": tilting = true; break;
            }

            setTimeActivity();

            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            String[] key;
            key = user.getEmail().split("@");
            reference.child("Position").child(key[0]).child("latlng").setValue(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));

        }
    }
```

But I want this method to run when MainActivity is down. I read about this thing and there are two ways to do the same: with service or with onStop method.

I prefer the second way, with onStop method, but I don't know how to call onLocationChanged in onStop method.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by `onStop` ?

Comment: a method who is called when the activity is down

Comment: you cannot use that method . you have to start the location service and wait for it to get the lat-long (`onLocationChanged`) so i don't think you can simply get the location from `OnStop` . you need to use service so when your activity died call the location service and do your last thing and shut that down too

Comment: You want to track location while your app is in background?

Comment: @dpaksoni yes, and i don't know how

Answer (score 2):

I hope this could help you.
In Android, there are location manager, which provides access to system location service.
You can fire `onLocationChanged` event by using this class.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Get the best provider  for the criteria
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

String bestprovider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,false);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestprovider,0, 0, this);
```

If you insert some of this code in `onStop` method, the `onLocationChanged` event will be fired.

Answer (score 1):

Override your onStop method and get the user's last known location in this manner

```
fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
    .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
    }
```

refer this link for more detail https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current now that you got the user's location under the call back of onSuccessListener you can update the location to your Firebase Database/Server

**Note** Depending on your requirements you can run this code on a main thread or on a different thread

Comment: I will try, Thanx :)